# Datasource is not bound in context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf-2, tomcat7

My datasource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <datasource>
        <local-tx-datasource>
            <jndi-name>SampleDS</jndi-name>
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://www.mycomp.com:3306/mydb                </connection-url>
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <min-pool-size>
                1>/min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>
                    20>/max-pool-size>
    admin</user-name>
                        <password>admin</password>
                        <metadata>
                            <type-mapping & g ; mySQL</type-mapping>
                        </metadata>
        </local-tx-datasource>

</datasource>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="DefaultPersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>User</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://www.mycomp.com:3306/mydb" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="SampleDS" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

UserList.java

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DefaultPersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createQuery(CityList.EJBQL);
    List<User> users= query.getResultList();

    return users;
}
```

After deploying when accessing my xhtml page I am getting the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DefaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at com.myapp.action.UserList.getUsers(UserList.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:165)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:351)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:160)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1670)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name SampleDS is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
    ... 58 more
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

With the [hibernate.connection.datasource](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#d0e1858) property, you're telling hibernate to look for a datasource in JNDI. Obviously you don't have one. Since you're specifying all the other required connection properties there, I'm guessing you don't really mean to do that.

Comment: How to keep my SampleDS in the naming context?

Comment: Since you appear to be using Tomcat, try the [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).